# Linux: concatenate each pair of files in a directory

Tags: linux, unix

Under linux, in a directory I have multiple files, say n, denoted as file1, file2 ... filen.

I want to concatenate each pair of them. Basically, there are "n choose 2" possible pairs.

like:

```
file1_file2

file1_file3

...

file1_filen

file2_file3

file2_file4

...

file2_filen

...
```

I want to use linux command, like cat. could anyone tell me how to use a loop to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by *"n choose 2"*?

Comment: Why not just created a pair of nested for loops? If you need to know how to do it, look up information on shell scripting (probably bash scripting on most systems).

Comment: @konsolebox because I want to concatenate each pair of n files, so it actually "n choose 2"/2 combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Try simply

```
 for i in file*; do
   for j in file*; do
      cat $i $j >> result_folder/$i_$j;
      rm result_folder/$j_$i 2>/dev/null
   done
 done
```

Comment: This is an incomplete answer. It will leave the user with duplicate pairings (file1_file2 and file2_file1), which he seems not to want, and also doesn't account for file1_file1, etc.

Comment: Thanks, @DanFego, added a if sentence that removes duplicates.

Comment: $i and $j are alphanumeric.  -lt requires integers.

Comment: @hymie you are right. The command "for i in file*.txt; do for j in file*.txt; do if [ ${i} -lt ${j} ]; then cat ${i} ${j} >> result/$i_$j; fi; done;done" end with error: 
-bash: [: file1.txt: integer expression expected

Answer (score 1):

Here you go (rev 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 10`; do
    for j in `seq $((i+1)) 10`; do
        cat file$i file$j >file${i}_file${j}
    done
done
```

Comment: you will have incorrect pairings such as file1_file1 and file3_file1.  i should run from 1 to 9 and j should run from i+1 to 10, but my bash skills aren't quite that strong to show you myself.

Comment: Thank, this will end up with a problem I had before. From the second loop on, the new generated files (like file1_file2) will be used in the following loop to concatenate with others, and will end with files like file1_file2_file3, for ever.

Comment: @hymie see new version above. Jun Cheng: No, it will not create file1_file2_file3
The output will now create 45 files (10 C 2)